# How NSString containing "&" convert to " \u0026" in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

Eg :"Transport & Logistics" to "Transport  \u0026 Logistics"

Comment: so, he wants to know basics

Comment: character & can't be specified by a universal character name . Then how

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are trying to do is to convert Text to Unicode Hex Representation.

the code below:

```
    NSString *amp = @"&";
    char ch = [amp characterAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"amp is %04x", ch);
```

printing out in console: **amp is 0026**

(4 in %04x is number of characters to log)
now the deal is to represent 0026 as \u0026,
you can use stringWithFormat method of NSString, to achieve the result, if you want it as string.

And it is not clear, if you need to convert only ampersand - you should search for it in string.

Comment: How u achive a Nsstring  \u0026 with stringwithformat

Comment: NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\\u%04x", ch];

Comment: it will always have \\ instead of \ , Even take substring as 1 to 5 from String , it will remove "\\" both not single "\" . Have you checked it?

Answer (score 0):

The & is \u0026  in unicode characters and the bootstrap will accept %26 as &